# Personalized database Connection string for C# application

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

I am trying to have a personalized database connection string for the machines i install the C# application into. I have created a database using Visual Studio but that only points the location of the database to my personal directory and that is not something general.
Now when i try to publish the application and try to install it in some other computer, the database gives me an error that it wasnt found, which makes sense because the connection string is pointing to my personal computers directory.

Here is part of my code:

```
 private void button13_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Program Files\\Hydrolec Inc\\PanelProgressLogger\\PanelProgress.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
         sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT [Panel Progress].*
                                    FROM [Panel Progress]", con);
         fill_grid();
     }
     catch (Exception error)
     {
         label6.Text = error.Message;
     }
 }
```

Can anyone please guide me towards the right path to solve this issue and to generate a personalized connection string for every computer the database gets installed to?

Comment: This is a great use case for config files.  Put the connection string in the app.config file and change it on the destination machine.  You can also use Settings to store configuration info.

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag reads:  "Do not use this tag unless you have a specific question about Visual Studio - not just a coding issue."  I can't remove the tag at this time; there is a pending edit that needs approval before that can happen.

Comment: I still don't even see where the connection string is pointing to your computer. Do you mean the file path might change?

Comment: Thank you D Stanley for the reply. But i did try that and use a differnt connection string, for instance: C\\Program Files\\Folder name\\project name\\PanelProgress.mdf;
and still it didnt go through and returned an error with it.

Comment: Amy,
I will keep that in mind next time i have a question.

Comment: itsme86,
The connection string is this: ("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Program Files\\Hydrolec Inc\\PanelProgressLogger\\PanelProgress.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");

now if i publish this application and install it on some other computer, the sqlconnection string remains the same pointing to my c drive rather than the c drive of the published computer.

Comment: @Ammar, if you have more information please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41304588/edit) your question, do not put code or details in comments.

Answer (score -1):

In your app.config or web.config file (Whichever is relevant to you) add the following connection string under configuration tag.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Program Files\\Hydrolec Inc\\PanelProgressLogger\\PanelProgress.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

If you already have a connection strings section then add only the

```
    <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Program Files\\Hydrolec Inc\\PanelProgressLogger\\PanelProgress.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;" />
```

Then in your C# code instead of hard coding the connection string you can use the config value.

```
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;

    private void button13_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT [Panel Progress].*
                                FROM [Panel Progress]", con);
            fill_grid();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            label6.Text = error.Message;
        }
    }
```

Build it. Then when you deploy the application in to another machine all you have to do is change your connection string in the app.config or web.config(whichever is relevant for you) to the new file location without changing hard coded values and rebuilding the application again.

Comment: Appreciate your reply Buddhi.
I tried your method but it only works on my computer. As soon as i install the application on some other computer, it gives me the following error "A netwrok related or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server"

Do i need to install sql express or server on every computer i install this application to? or is there any method to get this resolved?

Comment: If you analyze the connection string "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS" that means it refers the SQLExpress in the local machine. (The dot represents the  machine which is application is being hosted.) You are getting the error because there is no SQL instance in that machine. If you have a networked environment then you can refer another accessible DB server by changing the DataSource to that "<server name>\\SQLExpress" in the connection string.